# Recursively iterate through files in a directory

Tags: bash, directory, recursive

Recursively iterating through files in a directory can easily be done by:

```
find . -type f -exec bar {} \;
```

However, the above does not work for more complex things, where a lot of conditional branches, looping etc. needs to be done. I used to use this for the above:

```
while read line; do [...]; done < <(find . -type f)
```

However, it seems like this doesn't work for files containing obscure characters:

```
$ touch $'a\nb'
$ find . -type f
./a?b
```

Is there an alternative that handles such obscure characters well?

Comment: `find ... -exec bash -c 'echo filename is in \$0: "$0"' {} \;` is a better way to do it.

Comment: You can solve this, and keep your original design, by changing your `read line` to `IFS= read -r line`. The only character that will break it then is a newline.

Comment: @Patrick, but filenames can contain newlines.  That's why `-d $'\0'` is preferable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yet another use for [safe `find`](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/examples/safe-find.sh):

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' -u 9
do
    [Do something with "$REPLY"]
done 9< <( find . -type f -exec printf '%s\0' {} + )
```

(This works with any POSIX `find`, but the shell part requires bash. With *BSD and GNU find, you can use `-print0` instead of `-exec printf '%s\0' {} +`, it will be slightly faster.)

This makes it possible to use standard input within the loop, and it works with *any* path.

Comment: Because I had to look it up: "read ... If no names are supplied, the line read is assigned to the variable REPLY."

So `do echo "Filename is '$REPLY'" `

Answer (score 9):

Doing this is as simple as:

```
find -exec sh -c 'inline script "$0"' {} \;
```

Or...

```
find -exec executable_script {} \;
```

Comment: The first example gave a whole bunch of `inline: not found` errors for me, but this does what I expect `find -exec sh -c 'echo inline script "$0"' {} \;`.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest (yet safe) approach is to use shell globbing:

```
$ for f in *; do printf ":%s:\n" "$f"; done 
:a b:
:c
d:
:-e:
:e  f:
h:
```

To make the above recurse into subdirectories (in bash), you can use the `globstar` option; also set `dotglob` to match files whose name begins with `.`:

```
$ shopt -s globstar dotglob
$ for f in **/*; do printf ":%s:\n" "$f"; done 
:a b:
:c
d:
:-e:
:e  f:
:foo:
:foo/file1:
:foo/file two:
h:
```

Beware that up to bash 4.2, `**/` recurses into symbolic links to directories. Since bash 4.3, `**/` recurses only into directories, like `find`.

Another common solution is to use `find -print0` with `xargs -0`:

```
$ touch -- 'a b' $'c\nd' $'e\tf' $'g\rh' '-e'
$ find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} printf ":%s:\n" {}
h:/g
:./e    f:
:./a b:
:./-e:
:./c
d:
```

Note that the `h:/g` is actually correct since the file name contains a `\r`.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit difficult to do your read loop portably, but for bash in particular you can try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039130/bash-iterate-over-list-of-files-with-spaces).

Relevant portion:

```
while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file ; do
        printf 'File found: %s\n' "$file"
done < <(find . -iname 'foo*' -print0)
```

That instructs `find` to print its output delimited by NUL characters (0x00), and `read` to fetch NUL-delimited lines (`-d $'\0'`) without handling backslashes as escapes for other characters (`-r`) and not do any word splitting on the lines (`IFS=`).  Since 0x00 is a byte that can't occur in filenames or paths in Unix, this should handle all of your weird filename problems.

Comment: `-d ''` is equivalent to `-d $'\0'`.