# bash script split file names

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for r in $(find . -name "*.fastq");
do

  cat <<EOF
  #qsub <<EOF
#!/bin/bash -l

#PBS -N $r

EOF

done
```

Unfortunately, all filename get split:

```
> sh  cFiltering_pbs.sh 
  #qsub <<EOF
#!/bin/bash -l

#PBS -N ./76A

  #qsub <<EOF
#!/bin/bash -l

#PBS -N Paired.fastq

  #qsub <<EOF
#!/bin/bash -l

#PBS -N ./104A

  #qsub <<EOF
#!/bin/bash -l

#PBS -N Paired.fastq
```

Here is the find output:

```
find . -name "*.fastq"
./76A Paired.fastq
./104A Paired.fastq
```

What did I miss?

Comment: `for r in $(find . -name "*.fastq");` is [pretty bad...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/22142)

Comment: Are all your `fastq` files in the same directory?

Comment: yes,  they're all in the same directory. I solved it with this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9499/34872

Comment: That's a poor solution for your situation

Comment: see: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) and [Recursively iterate through files in a directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139363/recursively-iterate-through-files-in-a-directory) and also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `find` you can simply loop through the files themselves. Notice that I have double-quoted `"$r"`; you need to do that to keep the space in the filenames intact and unparsed by the shell.

```
for r in *.fastq
do
    # Stuff using "$r"...
    :
done
```